# Solve $x^2=\cos x$ using Taylor series for cosx

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I have the following equation:$x^2=\cos x$ and calculating the Taylor series of $3rd$ degree  around $0$ I've got:    $x\approx \pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$

However, now I need to prove that if x is a solution, then $\frac{\sqrt{5}}{3}\le|x|\le\frac{\sqrt{7}}{3}$

Bounding the remainder of the Taylor expansion we have: $|R|\le \frac{|x^3|}{6}$ ,then I don't know what to do, what should I do next?.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you worked with this function?: $f(x)=x^2-\cos(x)$

Comment: Yes but I might be doing something wrong because I can´t get to a conclusion

Comment: I do not understand what you want to prove. According to [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^2%3Dcos+x), $x^2=\cos x$ does not have an algebraic solution (and, by the way, $\sqrt{{2\over 3}}$ is not a solution).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli. I agree but it is very close to the solution : $\sqrt{{2\over 3}}\approx 0.816497$ while the first root of the equation is $\approx 0.824132$

Comment: Oh, ok, @ClaudeLeibovici Sorry, I misread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function
$$f(x):=\cos x-x^2=1-{3\over2}x^2+{1\over24}x^4-\ldots$$
is monotonically decreasing for $x>0$, since $f'(x)=-\sin x -2x<0$ for positive $x$. Therefore it has at most one positive zero $\xi$. When $|x|<1$ the subsequent terms of the Taylor series are decreasing in absolute value; therefore we know that
$$1-{3\over2}x^2<f(x)<1-{3\over2}x^2+{1\over24}x^4\qquad(0<x<1)\ .$$
It follows that
$$f\left({\sqrt{5}\over3}\right)>1-{3\over2}\cdot{5\over9}={1\over6}>0$$
and
$$f\left({\sqrt{7}\over3}\right)<1-{3\over2}\cdot{7\over9}+{49\over24\cdot 81}<-{1\over6}+{54\over24\cdot 81}=-{5\over36}<0\ .$$
Therefore $\xi$ lies between the claimed bounds.

Comment: What do you mean with at most one positive zero?

Comment: There cannot be more than one positive zero, even though $\cos$ is oscillating.On the other hand $x\mapsto e^{-x}$ is monotonically decreasing, and has no positive zero.

Answer (score 0):

**Sketch**

$\def\rr{\mathbb{R}}$$\cos(x) \in 1 - \frac{1}{2} x^2 + [0,\frac{1}{24}] x^4$ for any $x \in \rr$. [See note]

Thus $\cos(x) - x^2 \in 1 - \frac{3}{2} x^2 + [0,\frac{1}{24}] x^4$ for any $x \in \rr$.

Now all you need is to show that $\cos(x) - x^2$ is positive for $x^2 \le \frac{5}{9}$ and negative for $x^2 \ge \frac{7}{9}$.

**Note**

This kind of inequality for $\cos$ (and $\sin$) is obtained by repeatedly differentiating both sides since they are equal at $0$.